# Semantic names for shift-click and ctrl(or cmd)-click?

Tags: terminology, keyboard, mouse

I'm implementing something that uses shift-click and ctrl-click (cmd on the Mac) in the normal way. Shift-click lets you select a range of elements and ctrl-click lets you toggle the selection of single elements in the set.

I'd like a way to name the click act that is semantic and OS-agnostic, but can't find anything. Instead of having to pick CLICK+CTRL or CLICK+CMD as the value, I'd like to report CLICK+(something) that describes the action, not just names a key.

(In addition to the mouse action, I also have an action type, so I don't need to encode whether the element was selected or deselected, for example--just how the mouse and keyboard were used to cause the action.)

Anybody know a reasonably standard name or have any good suggestions? Everything I come up with seems either overly descriptive or slightly incorrect in edge cases.

My best tries are:

- CLICK_RANGE
- CLICK_MULTI
- CLICK_TOGGLE

At this point, I'm tempted to just give up and use CLICK_SHIFT and CLICK_CTRL.

Comment: Assuming that Shift+click also allows you to DEselect a range of elements then CLICK_SINGLE and CLICK_MULTI seems the obvious choice but this is only even going to be opinion based

Answer (score -1):

This functionality is often called *extended selection* (e.g. [SelectionMode.MultiExtended](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.selectionmode(v=vs.110).aspx) in .NET]), so I'd go with something like CLICK_EXTENDED.

Comment: For SHIFT or CTRL. And what name for the other one? :-)